# Elasticsearch OR operation between phrases

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

Is it possible in elasticsearch to get all documents that contain phrase1 OR phrase2 in a single query?
I know to match a phrase, one can use the following query:

```
"query" : {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "title" : "rock climbing"
        }
    }
```

But how about a case when there are multiple phrases and the goal is to retrieve documents containing either of these phrases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the two `match_phrase` queries in the `should` clause of a [bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query) :

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase" : {
            "title" : "phrase1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "title": "phrase2"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match": 1
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform [Query String](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) search

```
{
    "query_string" : {
        "default_field" : "content",
        "query" : "this AND that OR thus"
    }
}
```

You can specify the AND / OR clause in query or use `default_operator` and just write keywords to `query` parameter. If you want exact phare, just wrap the words to quotes.

Comment: This depends on how the field "title" was mapped in your index. If your Tokenizer (link below) is set to "whitespace" then the two terms can be searched individually and this answer will return the desired result.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/standard-tokenizer.html