# Using OR in the match query

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I add 2 or more search terms in the query part?
Using sql I can do:

```
query = '35.171.69.170' OR query = '1.2.3.4' OR query = '5.6.7.8'
```

But I am not sure how to update this elastic query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "sourceIPAddress": {
        "query": "35.171.69.170",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried following query and it seems to be working. I will like to know if this is correct approach:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query": " (35.171.69.170)  OR (1.2.3.4)",
            "fields": ["sourceIPAddress"]
        }
}
```

Is it possible to provide list to the field like:

```
"query": ["35.171.69.170", "1.2.3.4"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch OR operation between phrases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595889/elasticsearch-or-operation-between-phrases)

Comment: Please also provide your index mapping, so others can understand how the field `sourceIPAddress` and query string are analyzed.

Comment: @emix Yes. This question seems to be duplicate of that one. I can use a) Query String search or b) wrap two match_phrase queries in the should clause of a bool query. Do I have any other (third) option? Is it possible to supply a list?